# Somewhere in my array of objects, values change after running the same line of code?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

Basically, I have 2 arrays and handlers. One for spawning items, and one handles the obstacles. What happens though, is after a while the values change and are out of center. I'll provide a screenshot. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR7ae.png But, the code for spawning the items and obstacles doesn't change, what could be effecting this?

I've looked over my code so many times and I can't find what's causing this.

I am populating the coins in the center of the obstacles and once one is picked up or goes off screen, that bit of code is run. 
**Here is how I am populating my coins and obstacles.**

```java
private void populateCoins() {

        currY = (-5 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4) - (obstacleGap / 2) + (obstacleHeight);
        while (currY < 0) {
            xStartCoin = (int) (Math.random() * (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - obstacleHeight));
            coins.add(new Coin(obstacleHeight, colour, xStartCoin, currY));
            currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
        }
    }

 private void populateObstacles() {
        int currY = (-5 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4);
        while (currY < 0) {
            int xStart = (int) (Math.random() * (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
            obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, colour, xStart, currY, playerGap));
            currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
        }
    }
```

**Here is how I am spawning my obstacles and coins.**

```java
obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, colour, xStart,
obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - Constants.OBSTACLE_HEIGHT - Constants.OBSTACLE_GAP, 
(int)Constants.PLAYER_GAP));

coins.add(0, new Coin(obstacleHeight, colour, xStartCoin,
coins.get(0).getRectangle().top - Constants.OBSTACLE_GAP + Constants.OBSTACLE_HEIGHT));
```

It's after playing the game for about 60s the coins start to creep up the screen, no longer in the centre.

All I need is for the coins to stay centered in between the obstacles.